# Returning Multiple Tables Conditionally through UDF in SQL Server 2005

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005

i was wondering, if there is way to return choice of table conditionally in User Defined function(UDF) in SQL Server 2005.

I have wrote code like:

```
create function getMultiple(@flag int)
returns table
as
return
if @flag = 1
   select * from employee where xyz>100
else
  select * from managers where pqr>200
end
```

It does not compile and throws error on If statement and other errors.
Please help me modify same to achieve table depending on flag.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this but the table returned must look the same in both queries.

Multi statement version

```
create function GetMulti(@Flag int)
returns @T table (F1 int, F2 varchar(50))
as
begin
  if @Flag = 1
  begin
    insert into @T
    select
      EmpID,
      EmpName
    from Employee
  end  
  else
  begin
    insert into @T
    select
      ManagerID,
      ManagerName
    from Manager
  end  
  return
end
```

Inline version using union

```
create function GetMulti2(@Flag int)
returns table
as return
(
  select
    EmpID as F1,
    EmpName as F2
  from Employee
  where
    @Flag = 1
  union all
  select
    ManagerID as F1,
    ManagerName as F2
  from Manager
  where
    @Flag <> 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No this isn't possible with either an inline or multi statement TVF (unless the 2 tables are union compatible?)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following... If the column values are not the same between the 2 selects, you can do a convert for each one to match them.

```
create procedure getMultiple @flag int  as
begin 
if @flag = 1
   select convert(varchar, myColumnB1) from MyTable where myColumnB2>100
else
  select convert(varchar, myColumnC2) from MyOtherTable where myColumnC3 between '4/28/2006' and '4/30/2006' 

end
```

Comment: Note... This is a stored procedure solution... rather than a UDF solution.